# Convert-vhd or get-vhd throws WMI error - The Hyper-V Management Tools could not access an expected WMI class on computer

Tags: powershell, hyper-v, vhd

I'm trying to convert a VHD to VHDX using the `convert-vhd` command but I get the following error:

> The Hyper-V Management Tools could not access an expected WMI class on computer 'WINHIF3'. This may indicate that the Hyper-V Platform is not installed on the computer or that the version of the Hyper-V Platform is incompatible with these management tools.

I get the same error if I use the get-vhd command.

However, if I use the HyperV Manager GUI I can convert the disk to VHDX.

Running on Server 2016 with the RSAT HyperV Management tools and powershell modules install

Any ideas?

Or is there any other way to convert a VHD to VHDX via command line?

Comment: Since you can run the HyperV Management GUI the Hyper-V Platform in installed and the correct version.  It sounds like the cmdlet is not on the PSModulePath.  Try running you PS code from the folder where Hyper-V Platform was installed so the PSModulePath is not needed.  You can edit the PSModulePath by typing in the start button : Edit Environmental Variables for your account.

Comment: Did you run the command as administrator?

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the module, because if I enter convert-vhd and press enter it asks for a path.
Yes, I am running the command as administrator.

Comment: Is there any other way to convert a VHD to VHDX other than the convert-vhd command? Has to be command line though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out in "Turn Windows features on or off" I'd only enabled "Hyper-V Management Tools". Once I added "Hyper-V Platform" (which required a reboot) it worked.

[image]